# BizTalk Xml disassembler not promoting properties

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I have defined a schema with several promoted properties.

I have a two way send port that calls a rest service.
The rest service returns a response matching the message schema.  The receive pipeline for the two way send port has an xml disassembler component in it.

[image]

I also have a two way receive port.
The receive pipeline of the receive port has a component that publishes multiple messages into the queue so they are available using the GetNext() function.  One of the messages matches the schema I published.  The next component in the pipeline is an xml disassembler component.

[image]

I would have thought that in both ports, because my receive port has an xml disassembler, it would publish the promoted properties of the message so that I can subscribe to them in send ports, The values are not being promoted and I don't know why that is.

Here is my message schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://MyMessage" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns0="https://MyMessageProperties.PropertySchema" targetNamespace="http://MyMessage" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:imports xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">
        <b:namespace prefix="ns0" uri="https://MyMessageProperties.PropertySchema" location=".\PropertySchema.xsd" />
      </b:imports>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  
  <xs:element name="MessageProcessingResult">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:properties>
          <b:property name="ns0:Category" xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageProcessingResult' and namespace-uri()='http://MyMessage']/*[local-name()='Category' and namespace-uri()='']" />
          <b:property name="ns0:Code" xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageProcessingResult' and namespace-uri()='http://MyMessage']/*[local-name()='Code' and namespace-uri()='']" />
          <b:property name="ns0:ComponentOfOrigin" xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageProcessingResult' and namespace-uri()='http://MyMessage']/*[local-name()='ComponentOfOrigin' and namespace-uri()='']" />
          <b:property name="ns0:OriginalMessageTypeValue" xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageProcessingResult' and namespace-uri()='http://MyMessage']/*[local-name()='OriginalMessageType' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Value' and namespace-uri()='']" />
          <b:property name="ns0:OriginalMessageID" xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageProcessingResult' and namespace-uri()='http://MyMessage']/*[local-name()='OriginalMessageID' and namespace-uri()='']" />
        </b:properties>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="Category">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="Success" />
              <xs:enumeration value="Problem" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="ComponentOfOrigin" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="OriginalMessageID" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="OriginalMessageType" type="Type" />        
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  
  <xs:complexType name="Type">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Value" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
  
</xs:schema>
```

Here is my property schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://MyMessageProperties.PropertySchema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="https://MyMessageProperties.PropertySchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo schema_type="property" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element default="Problem" name="Category" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="676ad92f-16de-42df-8758-6b92dc4816a6" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element default="Unkown" name="Code" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="74bf0ac9-fe44-4ef1-a27c-64afe0e334bb" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element default="Unknown" name="ComponentOfOrigin" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="860e8876-8a0e-4fbd-aebe-84ee12bfb041" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element default="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" name="OriginalMessageTypeValue" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="4d329f1d-4944-46e0-9ec9-4b87eb8d7a71" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element default="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" name="OriginalMessageID" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="5bc4a75a-8fb3-4b54-becc-89e5415d216d" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that only ONE dissembler will execute.

Notice the graphics in the Disassemble stage vs the Decode stage.

[image]

The Decode components will fire in sequence, but the Disassemble stage will probe which component matches the message, and the first one that matches will fire, and only that one.

[Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/pipelines) (Microsoft)

> As an example of execution modes, the Disassemble stage of a receive pipeline is a First Match stage, thus each component in the stage is called to see if it recognizes the message and can process it. If the component responds in the affirmative, then no other components in that stage are queried to see if they can also handle the message. However, the Decode stage of a receive pipeline has an execution mode of All, meaning that each component in this stage is called to process the message in the order in which they were configured. The first decoder might be to decrypt the message, while the second might be to decompress the message from a zipped format.

So if you want to promote properties and also de-batch, you need to do in both your custom Disassembler.

e.g.

```
outMsg.Context.Promote(Name, Namespace, PropertyValue);
```

Comment: can I somehow call the xml dissassembler inside my custom component?  Or can I put the disassemblers in other stages?

Comment: Also, one of my pipelines (for handling the respone from a rest service)  only has one disassembler component (the xml one).

Comment: @Jeremy  If you are doing de-batching, then no, you can only have that in the disassembler stage.  Why would you want to call the XML dissasembler? It sounds like your custom dissasembler is already producing a XML output, all you have to do is add a a few lines in your code to promote the properties you want.  So the response one should be fine, or are you having a problem there as well?

Comment: this particular message can be created in a number of places, so if I was able to not have to do promotion myself and just use xml disassembler I thought it would be a more elegant implementation.  The weird thing is that as a test I created a file receive location with just an xml receive pipeline, and even that does not promote the properties automatically.

Comment: I tested your schemas  with a file receive and it did promote the properties. You can only  use the GetNext and publish multiple messages in a he Disassembler stage

Comment: did you have any additional configuration on your Xml Disassembler, like  DocumentSpecName or anything?

Comment: @Jeremy No, no additional settings

Comment: OK thanks.   I removed my properties promotions and deleted the property schema file, and recreated using quick promote,  seems to work now